Why am I still seeing Grafana Live API calls despite setting max_connections to zero?
In my grafana helm values.yaml I have specified the following
grafana.ini:
  live:
    max_connections: 0

This is based on the documentation that says "0 disables Grafana Live".
I have synced the Grafana StatefulSet and double checked the ConfigMap has this property set in the live manifest.
However, I am still seeing error logs in the api gateway for GET /api/live/ws returning 401 and it is coming from a grafana http route.

this issue suggests setting the env var GF_LIVE_MAX_CONNECTIONS to zero. I have done that by editing the live manifest of the StatefulSet (...spec.containers.env[]) but that did not work either.

I opened a shell into a pod of the StatefulSet and confirmed the environment variable is set /usr/share/grafana $ printenv ... GF_LIVE_MAX_CONNECTIONS=0 ...
